# Unit test to check if debug.assert statement is called in code

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have some Assert statements to check some conditions for developers. So when developer is debugging if this condition fails then `Assert` should fail and warn developer.
I want to write Unit test to see if this assert gets called in debug mode and ignored in Release mode.

Comment: You'll need an `observer` or `spy`, but first, it would be nice to see the code to test.

Comment: Testing to check if the C# compiler properly implements the [Conditional] attribute is not useful.  It does.